# Parse Increment feature doesn't increment over value of 1

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I've been trying to get a registration/login form going on in my android application, and I've been trying to do so with the help of the Parse Core by storing users' information as an Object.

I've gotten everything to work perfectly. Well...almost.

The only thing that I need to do now is to add a unique user ID for every user registered and increment it by 1 everytime a new user registers.

I've tried using the `Users.increment("userID", 1);`, and it works, but it doesn't go over the value `1`.

[image]

This is what I'm trying to do:

[image]

This is my registration form code:

```
ParseObject Users = new ParseObject("Users");
Users.increment("userID", 1);
Users.put("first_name", firstname);
Users.put("last_name", lastname);
Users.put("email", email);
Users.put("password", password);
Users.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            //User registered successfully.
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration successful."
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Take user to LoginActivity.
            startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
        } else {
            //User registration failed.
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration failed."
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Show error.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `ParseObject user = new ParseObject("Users");` you are defining a new row of the table, so if you call `increment()` you will be incrementing just that row's value.

If you want to do something different I can help you out. The answer is different based on what you want to do:

- keep a total count of users;
- add a unique identifier to each user;
- ...

and *why* you want to do it. Note that each user has *already* a unique identifier, in the `objectId` field, and that can be helpful in most, if not all, applications.

---

Ok, now I have seen your second screenshots and understand what you are trying to achieve. That is surely possible, but I would discourage it. For example, let's say you manage to write working code. What happens if..:

- The user with userID = 1 deletes his account? Are you going to scale down the userIDs of all the users that registered after (userID = 2, 3, ...)? That is hard and mostly useless.
- Two or more users register at the same time? That would determine serious synchronization issues and you could end up having two (or more) users with the same userID.

So my answer is: what you want is possible only with hard work, and probably useless. If you give additional info about why you want to do that, we can find a better way.

Comment: Ah. How do I then increment the "userID" value of the previous user? Is there any way around it? Thanks.

Comment: Now I understood and I edited my answer. Why do you want to do that? It is better to stick with the objectId field for uniqueness.

Comment: EDIT: I didn't realize those types of problems would occur. Thanks for clearing things up. I'm really new to Parse, so some things seem very simple yet hard to achieve. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. A second tip: for users it is better to use the provided ParseUser class, don't create a new one :-)

Comment: Well, I want the users' first name and last name to be stored too, but I couldn't really find a solution to that part, so I just created a new object. :P

Comment: That is easy! ParseUser user = new ParseUser(); user.put("first_name","Ultra"); user.saveInBackground(); . This will create a new column.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know you could add more columns to a default class. Thanks again dude. You've been really helpful!